# ADT opens as Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, adt

*i downloaded **ADT bundle for linux 64bit** from **developers android** website
also downloaded **adt plugin zip** and installed **developer tools** form **HELP --->> INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE**.
but **when i open eclipse** from the folder it opens as **eclipse juno (i.e.the splash screen) and not as Android Developer Tools.**
can anyone tell me what is wrong or am i openeing it the wrong way?*

and i am using **fedora 20**.

Comment: If you have downloaded ADT bundle, why do you want to download the plugin zip and install ADT plugin, Bundle already have the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but ADT is mainly context menus integration in Eclipse.  If you are in the `Java perspective` you can see on the Window menu the options Android SDK Manager, Android Virtual Devices, etc. You also have a perspective to debug called DDMS. You can create new project with template Android Project (or import Android project from existing sources). If you right click in a project you also have and Android Tools context menu, etc.

Comment: yes i have it all that you said !  See i am a beginner so i want to make sure everything is working fine. So does that mean i have installed it correctly  ?

Comment: Yes, that means everything is fine and you can start developing for Android ;-)